# Tessellation shader drawing issues

Tags: glsl, shader, tessellation

I am currently trying to add tessellation shaders to my program and I feel as though I'm at my wit's end. I have gone through several tutorials and delved into a lot of the questions here as well. Unfortunately I still do not understand what I am doing wrong after all of this. I will take any tips gladly, and do admit I'm a total novice here. My vertex and fragment shaders work, but no matter which tutorial I base my code off of, I can not get anything to display once I add tessellation shaders. I get no errors while loading, linking, or using the shaders/program either.

The four shaders in question:

**Vertex:**

```
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex;

out gl_PerVertex{
vec4 gl_Position;
};

void main()
{
gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
//note I have to multiply this by the MVP matrix if there is no tessellation
}
```

**Tessellation Control Shader:**

```
layout (vertices = 3) out;

out gl_PerVertex {
 vec4 gl_Position;
 } gl_out[];

void main()
{
if (gl_InvocationID == 0)
   {
   gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 3.0;
   gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 2.0;
   gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 2.0;
   gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 2.0;
   }
gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
}
```

**Tessellation Evaluation Shader:**

```
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, ccw) in;
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
out gl_PerVertex{
vec4 gl_Position;
};

void main()
{
 vec4 position =    gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position +
                    gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position +
                    gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position;
 gl_Position = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
void main()
{
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.1, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking some really simple stuff here, but I'm at an absolute loss here. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Can you add your actual GL draw calls to the code listing? If the code works with just vertex and fragment shaders, then I believe you are using the wrong primitive type. Tessellation Control Shaders expect patches, but no other kind of shader can make sense out of patch primitives - so that means you must not be drawing patches.

Comment: Thank you. You were correct there. It was an issue in my draw call. It does not display correctly, but it does display. That is enough that I can work with it at least. I was so focused on learning how to implement the shaders that I overlooked such a simple thing! If you post that as the answer, I will gladly mark it as solved.

Comment: I would gladly, but I am not sure what you changed? I gave you a suggestion, but for it to be useful in answer form, I would really need to see the original draw call that caused the problem.

Comment: I still had DrawElements outputting triangles from when I was swapping back and forth between testing shaders. It was a really dumb mistake. If I may push my luck, I have heard that quads are equally efficient to triangles in patches (performance wise). Do you know if this is true? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I couldn't really say for any performance difference. I have never actually compared that sort of thing ;) If there is any, it would be far less than the amount of performance wasted tessellating really small triangles/quads. That seems to be where most performance goes in tessellation before any optimization work is done; giving the same subdivision level to distant objects as nearby ones. And I don't think that triangles are any more prone to this problem than quads.

Comment: I, and granted I have learned everything I have known starting with very outdated tutorials, learned that triangles were always more efficient than quads, because they had to be broken up that way eventually anyways. With shaders that does not seem to be the case. Either way, I marked your answer as correct and thank you once more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you draw using a Tessellation Control Shader (this is an optional stage), you must use `GL_PATCHES` as the primitive type.

#### Additionally, `GL_PATCHES` has no default number of vertices, you must set that:

```
glPatchParameteri (GL_PATCH_VERTICES​, 3);
glDrawElements    (GL_PATCHES, 3, ..., ...);
```

The code listed above will draw a single triangle patch. Now, since geometry shaders and tessellation evaluation shaders do not understand `GL_PATCHES`, if you remove the tessellation control shader, the draw code will do nothing. Only the tessellation control shader can make sense out of `GL_PATCHES` primitive, and conversely it cannot make sense of any other kind of primitive.